# how to capture docker compose exec command in bash variable

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose

I am writing a bash script to check the status of a mongodb instance running in a docker container. This code validates that I can successfully execute the mongo command inside the container:

```
cat <<END | docker-compose exec -T mongodb1 mongo --username root --password passwd
rs.status().myState
END
```

However, I would like to be able to store the stdout of rs.status().myState in a variable. Something similar to this:

```
MY_STATE=$(docker-compose exec -T mongodb1 mongo --username root --password passwd &&
rs.status().myState)
```

But I get the exception: `uncaught exception: ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side`
How do I capture the output from the mongo shell running inside the container and store it in a variable?

Answer (score 1):

No matter what it looks like on your terminal, you can't write a shell script that first starts some program, and then second types some input into it.  That's what it looks like your last invocation is trying to do.  If you try to run something like

```bash
some-command && \
input to some-command
```

then first the command runs to completion, with no input, and then the shell tries to run the input as a second command.

Your first command is probably closer to something that would actually work.  If the input fits on a single line then I might write

```bash
echo 'input to some-command' | some-command
```

or, in the more specific case of your command,

```bash
MY_STATE=$(echo 'rs.status().mystate' | docker-compose exec -T mongodb1 mongo --username root --password passwd)
```

You might reconsider whether you actually need `docker-compose exec` here.  You can't run that without also having the ability to `docker run` a container that can take over the entire host system.  If you have the MongoDB command-line tools available on your host, and if you've published a port with the Compose `ports:` option, then it might work to skip the `docker-compose exec` part

```bash
MY_STATE=$(echo 'rs.status().mystate' | mongo --username root --password passwd)
```

If you're doing this for a health check, the other thing to consider is that, if a container's main process exits, the process will exit too.  That's not always a 100% guarantee and it's very possible for a container to not exit but also not be functional, maybe waiting for something in its environment to reappear (Kubernetes has much richer health checks).  But if you can rely on seeing the database server exit if it becomes unhealthy then you don't need a check like this at all.